# Unable to delete entities from command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to run import on non prod env using the prod exported data but do not know how to delete all the kids from command line before starting import. Since we are creating fake data for load testing, it is essential to delete all the kinds and perform fresh import. I can delete the kinds manually from datastore admin but would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: What kind of command line? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code is helpful. You can follow the below approach to delete all the entities from a kind problematically. First we are fetching all the entity from the kind and populating a list of keys and then selecting each entity using key and deleting it from datastore.

Step 1: Fetch all keys from datastore

```
List<String> googleDSKeyList = new ArrayList<String>();
StructuredQuery<Entity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setKind(kind).build();
    QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);

results.forEachRemaining(entity -> googleDSKeyList.add(String.valueOf(entity.getKey().getNameOrId())));
```

Step 2: For each entity, pass the key to the delete method.

```
googleDSKeyList.forEach(keyId-> deleteEntity(keyId));
```

Step 3: To delete the entity, perform select and then delete.

```
public void deleteEntity(String KEY_VALUE) {

    Query<Entity> query = Query
            .newGqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY,
                    "SELECT * WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY (" + KIND_NAME + ", '" + PRIMARY_KEY + "')")
            .setAllowLiteral(true).build();

    QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
    if (results.hasNext()) {
        Entity rs = results.next();
        datastore.delete(rs.getKey());
        LOGGER.info("Successfully Deleted KEY # : " + KEY_VALUE);
    }

}
```